# Lacquer on glassware

Tags: glass

I have some beer glasses with decal-like decorations that I assume are some kind of plastic or maybe even glass/faience. How are these made?

[image]

Comment: My guess is that it is Pyrography.

Comment: @Surb woodburning? how does that work in the context of glassware decals?

Comment: @Erica well Pyrography is usually done on wood but can also be applied on glass (note that there is nothing about "wood" in the word pyrography). [Some examples](https://www.google.de/search?q=Pyrogravure+sur+verre&espv=2&biw=1125&bih=636&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixr5Xuyc7RAhWrFZoKHYN-AcMQsAQIIA) (it might be my translation of "pyrogravure" which is wrong though...)

Comment: @Erica However, I guess your answer is correct (especially because of the different colors).

Comment: Ah -- I think that is more accurately _engraving_ (or perhaps etching, but I think that's chemical-based rather than mechanical) rather than burning.

Comment: @Erica Might be (I'm definitely not an expert :). Nevertheless, it seems that people use this technique "at home".

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely an **applied ceramic label**. It's an industrial process that can't be achieved in a typical handmade craft setting (e.g., your garage), requiring [ceramic inks](https://digitalfire.com/4sight/glossary/glossary_ceramic_ink.html) or enamels, screen printing to apply the design, and high-temperature baking to set.

*If you're considering removing an ACL to decorate the beer glass differently, the verdict is apparently that it isn't really removable ([see related Q/A](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/2072/30)).*